# Change color of only one data point in gnuplot

Tags: for-loop, animation, gnuplot, gif, animated-gif

I'm doing a gif in gnuplot, and I have my data separated in blocks. I need the points to be white except from *just* the first row of every data block, which would be an orange point.

Currently my code is:

```
#...
do for [i=0:int(STATS_blocks-1)]{
plot "positions.txt" index i pt 7 ps 0.5 lc 'white' title "t = ".((i+1)*200)." Myr"
}
```

As you can see, this plots every data point white, including the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edited to show variable pointsize also**

If I understand your data format correctly:

```
set linetype 11 lc "orange"
set linetype 12 lc "white"

set style data points
do for [i=0:N] {
  plot "positions.txt" index i using 1:2:(column(0)>0 ? 0.5 : 2.0):(column(0)>0 ? 12 : 11) pt 7 ps variable lc variable
}
```

Variable color (if used) is always taken from the very last `using` column. Other variable properties work back from there.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly. But what if I also wanted to change the pointsize of the first element and make it bigger, say ps 15 as opposed to ps 7 of the rest?